# Can I do everything BroadcastReceiver can do with JobScheduler?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-jobscheduler

I have an app that uses `BroadcastReceiver`*(`BR` for short)* registered in the **manifest** with `intent-filter` `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`.

This `BR` starts a `Service` when the phone is plugged, and when the phone is unplugged it will stop the `Service`.

This `Service` register another `BR` with `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, I did this because I want to register `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`'s `BR` when the phone is charging, and I used a `Service` to keep it registered even if the app is closed/destroyed.

The app is working perfect for every **API** level, except 27.

I know that in **API** 27 there is something with `BRs` like some restrictions, so I tried to figure what exactly is working, and what not.

I figured that the first `BR`*(the one in the **manifest**)* is never registered, and the another one is working *(I also start the `Service` in `onCreate` method of the main activity, so the second `BR` is registered when the app is opened)* but when I close the app the `Service` is automatically stopped/destroyed and thus the second `BR` will unregister.

In **API** level lower than 27 the `Service` wasn't automatically stopped/destroyed.

Someone told me:

> Why don't you try `IntentService`...

and then he said:

> You know, this idea is stupid, don't try it.

So I didn't try it.

Everyone in the web are saying use `JobScheduler`, and after a little look in `JobScheduler` I felt that `JobScheduler` is different from `BRs`

So my question is **Can I do everything `BroadcastReceiver` can do with `JobScheduler`?**
I mean can I make my whole app without `BRs` but with `JobScheduler`.

Answer (score 0):

No, `JobScheduler` is not here to replace `BroadcastReceiver`.

`BroadcastReceiver` let you notified of `System/Custom` Defined Set of event So that you can perform some task based on that.

`JobScheduler` allows you to `Schedule` some task which will execute when a `Defined Criteria` will met.

Just Look at definition there may be some overlapping in their work area but two perform very Separate Functions.

Edit For Comment:-

You can do this using `JobScheduler`, because this provides a way to perform some task when Charger Plug-In.

```
val jobBuilder = JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, ComponentName(this, SyncServices::class.java))
jobBuilder.setRequiresCharging(true)
val ss = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
ss.schedule(jobBuilder.build())
```

This will start `SyncServices` when Charger Plug-In.

Now From Sync Services You Can Perform Some Task and return a status finally where task completed or not based on that it will invoked again. You can find details about `JobScheduler` at (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)[here].

Comment: Thank you. But is there I way to make my app works on API level 27 and higher? To use Broadcast Receiver or something like it?

Comment: I have Edited my answer please check.

Comment: No, With broadcast receiver you will only get notified if you registered receiver grammatically after app startup and will get update untill app is open. All broadcast that send by system if not targeting a specific package will not support manifest broadcast registration.

Comment: You may use Foreground services if you want to get it work with minimal changes. But that will always show a notification.